# Как в pandas построить плавающее окно для группировки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть набор данных:

```
id  |  value
------------
1   |  3
2   |  4
3   |  6
4   |  7
5   |  2
```

Я хочу добавить сюда колонку со средним по предыдущим 3 строчкам c учетом текущей, чтобы результат был таким:

```
id  | value | my_column
-----------------------
1   | 3     |  3                   3/1
2   | 4     |  3.5             (3+4)/2
3   | 6     |  4.33          (3+4+6)/3
4   | 7     |  5.66          (4+6+7)/3
5   | 2     |  5             (6+7+2)/3
```

Пока я написал функцию, которая в цикле много раз проходит мой набор и считает эти суммы. Кажется, что можно обойтись без циклов. Можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In[114]: df
Out[114]: 
   id  value
0   1      3
1   2      4
2   3      6
3   4      7
4   5      2
```

Вы можете использовать *скользящее окно* размера `3`, с `min_periods=1` на колонку `df.value`:

> ```
> In[115]: df["my_column"] = df.value.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()
> In[116]: df
> Out[116]: 
>    id  value  my_column
> 0   1      3   3.000000
> 1   2      4   3.500000
> 2   3      6   4.333333
> 3   4      7   5.666667
> 4   5      2   5.000000
> ```

Comment: А я могу указывать сторону, в которую смотрит окно. И  наверное, должна быть какая то сортировка?

Comment: @Viktorov, отсортируйте DataFrame/Series перед вызовом `.rolling()`, например: `df['value'].sort_values().rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()`. По поводу "стороны, в которую смотрит окно" - трудно понять что вы имеете в виду без конкретного примера входных/выходных данных.